# XML output: A name was started with an invalid character

Tags: php, xml

When i echo the xml output i get the error in the title. What did i forget? 
Is the opening tag not right? I hope that someone can help me with this code.

I followed the instructions from the website http://www.mightywebdeveloper.com/coding/mysql-to-xml-php/

Thanx in advance.

```
<?php



$config['table_name'] = "tblPortalStatus";
//database configuration   
$serverName = "servername";
$connectionInfo = array( all info here);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);



$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblPortalStatus";

$params = array();
$options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );

$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params,$options);     




$xml          = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
$root_element = $config['table_name']."s"; //tblPortalStatus
$xml         .= "<$root_element>";



if (!sqlsrv_num_rows($result)) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . sqlsrv_error());
}

if(sqlsrv_num_rows($result)>0)
{
   while($result_array = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
   {
      $xml .= "<".$config['table_name'].">";

      //loop through each key,value pair in row
      foreach($result_array as $key => $value)
      {
         //$key holds the table column name
         $xml .= "<$key>";

         //embed the SQL data in a CDATA element to avoid XML entity issues
         $xml .= "<![CDATA[$value]]>";

         //and close the element
         $xml .= "</$key>";
      }

      $xml.= "</".$config['table_name'].">";
   }
}     


//close the root element
$xml .= "</$root_element>";

//send the xml header to the browser
header ("Content-Type:text/xml");

//output the XML data
echo $xml;
?> 



The XML page cannot be displayed 
Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later. 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

A name was started with an invalid character. Error processing resource 'http://PHP/Form.php'. Line 37, ...

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><tblPortalStatuss><tblPortalStatus><0><![CDATA[EPRC]]>&l...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an XML Api like XMLWriter or DOM to generate the XML. This will avoid most (but not all) problems. You might need to normalize field names before using them as tag names, fields can contain characters (like spaces) that are not allowed in tag names.

If you're a using an API you should get much better error messages as well.